# How to download large files (like weights of a model) from Colaboratory?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

I have tried downloading small files from google Colaboratory. They are easily downloaded but whenever I try to download files which have a large sizes it shows an error? What is the way to download large files?

Answer (score 19):

If you have created a large zip file, say my_archive.zip, then you can download it as following:

1. Mount your Google drive from your Google colab Notebook. You will
   be asked to enter a authentication code.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive',force_remount=True)
```

2. Copy the zip file to any of your google drive folder (e.g. downloads folder). You may also copy the file on 'My Drive' which is a root folder.

```
!cp my_archive.zip '/content/gdrive/My Drive/downloads/'
!ls -lt '/content/gdrive/My Drive/downloads/'
```

Finally, you can download the zip file from your Google drive to your local machine.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I handle this issue:

```
from google.colab import auth
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

auth.authenticate_user()
```

Then click on the link, authorize Google Drive and paste the code in the notebook.

```
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

def save_file_to_drive(name, path):
    file_metadata = {
      'name': name,
      'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream'
     }

     media = MediaFileUpload(path, 
                    mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                    resumable=True)

     created = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                   media_body=media,
                                   fields='id').execute()

     print('File ID: {}'.format(created.get('id')))

     return created
```

Then:

```
save_file_to_drive(destination_name, path_to_file)
```

This will save whatever files to your Google Drive, where you can download or sync them or whatever.

Comment: this gives me an error: media = MediaFileUpload(path,
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Try putting it all on one line: media = MediaFileUpload(path,                     mimetype='application/octet-stream', resumable=True)

Comment: what is the path_to_file? Is it a drive link or just an explicit path such as MyDrive/ models? @EricAntoineScuccimarra

Comment: path_to_file is the name you want to save the file as in Drive. If you can specify subdirectories I haven't been able to figure out how yet.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many different solutions. The only way that was effective and quick is to zip the file/folder and then download it directly:

```
 !zip -r model.zip model.pkl
```

And to download:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google colab doesn't allow you to download large files using `files.download()`. But you can use one of the following methods to access it:

1. The easiest one is to use github to commit and push your files and then clone it to your local machine.
2. You can mount google-drive to your colab instance and write the files there.

Comment: when I run the command - !git push -u origin master
It asks for my username and password. How ca I enter my username and password in the current running cell? Can not see a space where I can enter them.

Comment: @shivinsaluja You can't enter username and password. You will need to setup access to github using ssh: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: you cant do it also because sshj-keygen wants keyboard interaction