# Downloading a large file from colab fails

Tags: python-3.x, tar, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to download a directory which I've compressed as a .tar file, using the code below.  The .tar file seems to have downloaded but is much smaller than it is shown on colab.  Also I get the error message below.  Can someone please let me know what the error message below means and is there a better way to down load the files?

Code:

```
# compressing folder

!tar -cvf DVBPR.tar DVBPR/


# download files to local computer

from google.colab import files

files.download('DVBPR.tar')
```

Error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('::ffff:127.0.0.1', 59040, 0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 406, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 639, in do_GET
    self.copyfile(f, self.wfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 800, in copyfile
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, outputfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfileobj
    fdst.write(buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean). I think this generally occurs due to non-availability of a good internet connection. Try it when you have a good connection.

You can also try to mount your drive as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d) and then copy it onto your drive. Then download your file using a download manager.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I added a post below.  It solved my issue by saving the file to my google drive instead of downloading locally.

Comment: Good to know that.

Answer (score 0):

This post seemed to solve my issue.  Instead of downloading locally I saved it to my google drive using the code in the post:

[How to download large files (like weights of a model) from Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428332/how-to-download-large-files-like-weights-of-a-model-from-colaboratory)